# Ranking an array's values from 1 to 10, java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to rank an array's values into another array.
So the `array1`, the values(e.g `array1[3]`) needs to be ranked according to the size of the value and then needs to be assigned to a value from 1 to 10 depending on the size of the number. Ranked between 1 and 10.

I have tried doing selection sort:

```
public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr){

for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[index])
            index = j;

    int smallerNumber = arr[index]; 
    arr[index] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = smallerNumber;

}
```

Other than that, I dunno where to go. I tried 2d arrays but that's confusing.
The array1 would be shown in a column on the GUI screen but in a random order according to the program. But the ranking will be shown besides each value from the array1 column in the GUI. The ranking does not need to be shown in order but needs to rank the array1 values and shown besides the value on the next column on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried `Arrays.sort(array1);`?

Comment: Yeah, needs to show rank of 1 to 10 but not in order. So if the value of array1[1] is 2 and array1[2] is 4....it would show in the column of ranks: 2,1. 1 being the highest. Cheers :)

Comment: Will the values be unique?  If so you could make a copy of it into a list, sort it and then use the indexOf method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this kind of problem:

- Store the pairs of `(value, index)` in an array
- Sort the array of pairs by `value`
- Build the array of ranks from the sorted array of pairs

Something like this:

```
public static int[] calculateRanks(int... arr) {
    class Pair {
        final int value;
        final int index;

        Pair(int value, int index) {
            this.value = value;
            this.index = index;
        }
    }

    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[arr.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
        pairs[index] = new Pair(arr[index], index);
    }

    Arrays.sort(pairs, (o1, o2) -> -Integer.compare(o1.value, o2.value));

    int[] ranks = new int[arr.length];
    int rank = 1;
    for (Pair pair : pairs) {
        ranks[pair.index] = rank++;
    }

    return ranks;
}
```

This assumes that the values are unique, so the ranks will be unique too.
If there can be duplicate values, you can adjust the final step of setting the ranks accordingly.

For example, if there is at least one value in the array,
something like this would work:

```
    int[] ranks = new int[arr.length];
    ranks[pairs[0].index] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
        if (pairs[i].value == pairs[i - 1].value) {
            ranks[pairs[i].index] = ranks[pairs[i - 1].index];
        } else {
            ranks[pairs[i].index] = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the ranks are equal? How would I implement that?

Comment: In that case, instead of incrementing `rank` in each iteration, you will not increment the rank if the value is the same as the previous.

Comment: @TingAli I added an example implementation for that case

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array as the easiest solution. You wouldn't need to have a rank column since it is already in order. However, as you want it.

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{10, 22, 45, 6, 7, 25};
int[][] ranked = new int[array1.length][2];
for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++)
    ranked[i][0] = array1[i];
Arrays.sort(array1);

for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++)
    for(int n=0; n < array1.length; n++)
        if(ranked[n][0] == array1[i] && ranked[n][1] == 0) 
            ranked[n][1] = array1.length-i;
/* Result
10 # 4
22 # 3
45 # 1
6 # 6
7 # 5
25 # 2
*/
```

Comment: It should work now, fixed it one last time. `array1` becomes the temporary array but copies the values in the original order to the ranked list. Duplicate values do not matter.

Comment: what should I change to make this work with duplicate values (same values have same rank)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `array1` and store its values in a `TreeMap` as a key and the iterating counter(array index here) as its value.
`TreeMap` will sort itself based on the keys provided; you can iterate over the `TreeMap` and print the values, these are your corresponding ranks.

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{10, 22, 45, 6, 7, 25};
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
    map.put(array1[i],i);
}
for(int value : map.values()) {
    //print ranks in order of array values
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by ashfaq works good, but you should be aware of the fact that there are two types of ranking possible. I needed the other type, so I provide that sollution too, for completeness.

First on the two types of ranking.

In the R programming language, these are two different functions (note that R indexes start at 1, not at 0):

- order(5,6,4) will give 3, 1, 2, because the number at the third index is the lowest, than the number at the 1st index, then the number at the 2nd index.
- rank(5,6,4) will give 2, 3, 1, because 5 is the 2nd smallest number, 6 is the 3rd smallest, and 4 is the 1st smallest.

Now, ashfaq's solution gives what would be achieved in R via order().
Here below is a solution which mimic's R's rank() behaviour:

```
    int[] array1 = new int[] { 10, 22, 45, 6, 7, 25 };
    int[] sortedArray = array1.clone();
    Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        map.put(sortedArray[i], i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        sortedArray[i] = map.get(array1[i]);
        System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
    }
```